# Adding SOAP headers to ASMX service requests

Tags: c#, .net, soap, asmx, soapheader

We were given a set of ASMX services to consume. We have no say in how these services are implemented. We have generated a number of proxies with wsdl.exe tool but for some reason unknown to me, these generated proxies don't have any means for including custom SOAP headers.

Basically, I need a way to add custom header data to various service calls.

I am aware of existence of SoapExtension class but unfortunately we're not allowed to use that due to supposed performance issues.

Are there any alternative ways of customizing/adding header data in SOAP requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `SoapHeader` / `SoapUnknownHeader` to extend the generated proxy for this:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whew6x7f.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4t36w86.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader.aspx

EDIT - as per comments:

To include a custom namespace see the sample code [here](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/71/csharp-custom-soap-header/).

Comment: Awesome. Using SoapHeader attribute works for me. Do you have any idea how to ensure that elements in the soap header are assigned a proper custom namespace? Should I use [XmlType] attribute with Namespace property for that?

Comment: I needed to do the same found answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18886660/637142