# How to Authenticate SOAP service with OAuth Access token C#

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, soap, oauth

I am trying to connect to a SOAP API using C#. The API I use insists that I need to authenticate each API call with an OAuth Token. I have implemented the OAuth system and got the token I needed, But I am not sure how to Append it to the SOAP Call I am making. So I trid something like this

```
       var soapClient = new ReturnClient();
    soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyToken";
    soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyToken";
    var rrr = new RetrieveReturnRequest {RetrieveReturnRequestWrapper = xElem2};
    var response = soapClient.RetrieveReturn(rrr);
```

But this does not works and throws `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:`. Can anyone pointout what's the correct way to Authenticate a SOAP call with Access Token

Comment: What message you get in the Exception?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://apidomain/returns/. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, when you use OAuth, you need to pass the "token" using an HTTP Header. For OAuth2 and a bearer token, you will need to pass it in the `Authorization` HTTP header.

```
requestMessage.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer TOKEN_VALUE_HERE";
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886660/how-to-add-http-header-to-soap-client) for more details on how to pass an HTTP Header in a SOAP Client.