# Bearer authentication with System.Net.ICredentials

Tags: c#, jwt, wsdl, credentials

I have an application that compiles service reference assembly on-the-fly for given WSDL address:

1. Use System.Net.WebClient to *OpenRead* the target service as *Stream*
2. Describe the WSDL as Code Compile Unit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter

   *ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);*
3. Compile the unit into Assembly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromdom

All the services types in that assembly then have **Credentials** (type *ICredentials*) that can be set e.g.

```
someService.GetType().GetProperty("Credentials").SetValue(someService, new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
```

which works as expected in *Basic Authentication* scenario.

I now need to start supporting *Bearer authentication* (not sure if correct terminology) i.e. on the very request level of those services, have **Authorization** header with value **Bearer <token>**. <token> is jwt token obtained with OAuth2 protocol. The authentication itself works as I already use it to read the WSDL in step 1: *client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ...");*

However, I'm not able to use OperationContextScope to inject headers ([How to add HTTP Header to SOAP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886660/how-to-add-http-header-to-soap-client)) to my service reference calls because my compiled types do not contain *InnerChannel*.

I think under-the-hood *NetworkCredentials* result in header like *Authorization: Basic <credentials>*. This is so similar to what I need (*Authorization: Bearer <token>*) that I can't believe there simply isn't ICredentials sub-class for this purpose. Is there? Do I have any other options? I'm almost desperate enough to write my own proxy that forwards all my calls with that authorization header.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I happened to find a solution myself.

When the WSDL is imported into *CodeCompileUnit* with *ServiceDescriptionImporter*, all service types of the unit derive from *System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol*. This base class declaration can be replaced with a custom derivation of it, and thus override **GetWebRequest** and inject custom HTTP headers to all web requests of that service.

```
foreach(CodeNamespace ns in unit1.Namespaces)
{
  foreach(CodeTypeDeclaration t in ns.Types)
  {
    foreach(CodeTypeReference bt in t.BaseTypes)
    {
      if (bt.BaseType == "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol")
        bt.BaseType = "MyNamespace.MySoapHttpClientProtocol";
    }
  }
}
```

...

```
public class MySoapHttpClientProtocol : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
  {
    var req = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", ...);
    return req; 
  }
}
```

One important thing to remember is to add the current assembly that contains "*MySoapHttpClientProtocol*" to *CodeDomProvider* references before compiling the services into assembly.

In addition, I added

```
public string AuthToken { get; set; }
```

to *MySoapHttpClientProtocol* which is then injected as Authorization -header value at *GetWebRequest*. *AuthToken* can be accessed via reflection from the compiled types similar to how basic authentication was handled:

```
someService.GetType().GetProperty("AuthToken").SetValue(someService, "Bearer ...");
```