# How to add a HTTP header to ALL outgoing WCF requests?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I know it's possible to add a header to a WCF request, like described here: [How to add HTTP Header to SOAP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886660/how-to-add-http-header-to-soap-client/22998513#22998513)

```cs
Service1Client serviceClient = new Service1Client();
using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope((System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel)serviceClient.InnerChannel))
{
    System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("AdminGUID", "someGUID");
    serviceClient.GetData();
}
```

I have a use case, where I need to add such a header to all outgoing requests, and I would like to avoid wrapping every single WCF service method call in a using statement.

Is there a way to configure the ServiceSoapClient to add these headers to all requests?

Or maybe is there a way to generate a child class from the service reference, that would wrap all calls to base class, without doing it manually? A macro would be handy here...

Comment: With [message inspectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors) maybe? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call

Comment: @Bogdan Message inspectors were exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!